# Rotation set vs existence of rotation number

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, covering-spaces, discrete-dynamical-systems

Let $f\colon \mathbb{S}^{1}\to\mathbb{S}^{1}$ be a continuous function of degree 1 and $F\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ a lift of $f.$ One can define, for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$, the rotation number to be $$\rho\left(F,x\right)=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(F^{n}(x)-x\right)$$ and the rotation set $$\rho(F)=\overline{\left\{\rho\left(F,x\right) \ : \ x\in \mathbb{R}\right\} }.$$

This set can be either a single point or a closed interval.

When $f$ is an orientation-preserving homeomorphism, we can say more: that for every point $x\in \mathbb{R},$ the limit $$\rho\left(F,x\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(F^{n}(x)-x\right)$$ exists.

**My question**: I was told that, when $\rho(F)$ is an interval, there are points where the limit $\rho\left(F,x\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(F^{n}(x)-x\right)$ don't exist. How can I show it? Is there any simple example for degree one circle map $f$?

Comment: Let $I_+=[\frac 15,\frac 25]$ and $I_-=[\frac 35,\frac 45]$. Let $F$ be any map from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$ satisfying $F(0)=0$, $F(1)=1$, $F(x)=5x$ for $x\in I_+$ and $F(x)=5x-5$ for $x\in I_-$. Then extend $F$ to $\mathbb R$ by defining $F(x+n)=F(x)+n$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$. Now a standard dynamics argument shows that for any sequence $\epsilon_0,\epsilon_1,\ldots$ of +'s and $-$'s, you can find a point such that $F^j(x)\in I_{\epsilon_j}$ for each $j$. By taking  a sequence like +++-----------+++++++++++++++-----------------------------, it's easy to find points where the limit doesn't exist.